# Search inside ipython history

Tags: python, ipython

[ipython](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/)'s `%his` command outputs recent commands entered by the user. Is it possible to search within these commands? Something like this:

```
[c for c in %history if c.startswith('plot')]
```

**EDIT** I am not looking for a way to rerun a command, but to locate it in the history list. Of course, sometimes I will want to rerun a command after locating it, either verbatim or with modifications.

**EDIT** searching with `ctr-r` and then typing `plot` gives the most recent command that starts with "plot". It won't list all the commands that start with it. Neither can you search within the middle or the end of the commands

### Solution

Expanding PreludeAndFugue's solution here what I was looking for:

```
[l for l in  _ih if l.startswith('plot')]
```

here, the `if` condition can be substituted by a regex

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Similar to the first answer you can do the following:

```
''.join(_ih).split('\n')
```

However, when iterating through the command history items you can do the following. Thus you can create your list comprehension from this.

```
for item in _ih:
    print item
```

This is documented in the following section of the documentation:
http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/reference.html#input-caching-system

Comment: looks like the links gone bad.

Answer (score 67):

Even better: `%hist -g pattern` greps your past history for `pattern`. You can additionally restrict your search to the current session, or to a particular range of lines. See `%hist?`

So for @BorisGorelik's question you would have to do

```
%hist -g plot
```

Unfortunately you cannot do

```
%hist -g ^plot
```

nor

```
%hist -g "^plot"
```

Comment: WARNING: the pipes (`|`) above are part of the pattern being searched for, not some new magic regex or string literal delimiter. So if you're looking for the literal word "pattern" do not use any kind of string delimiter, just type `%history -g pattern`  If you use quotes or anything it will fail. And some regular expression characters will get gobbled up by the command line parser like `%history -g pattern?` will trigger the docstring help and fail, but %history -g patter[n] will work.

Comment: @hobs, does it actually run grep? with `extended regular expressions` syntax? even in Windows?

Comment: @alpha_989 unfortunately, ipython has chosen to only allow glob star search patterns, not regular expressions. I'm sure the awesome ipython maintainers would love your PR if you replaced their glob star pattern matcher with builtin python `re.findall()` regular expression search: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/history.py#L372

Comment: @hobs, thanks for point it out.. I will give it a shot. This would be super helpful to have!

Comment: @hobs Since people thought the pipes were confusing, I got rid of them.

Comment: Once you've found the command you're looking for, load it into editing mode via [`%recall`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-recall) using the session- and command-number shown by `%hist` (e.g. `%recall 12/34`). You can also [`%rerun`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-rerun) with the same syntax to re-run the command directly without editing it first.

Answer (score 20):

If you want to re-run a command in your history, try `Ctrl-r` and then your search string.

Comment: -1: Ctrl-r only works if IPython is being run in a Bash-style terminal (i.e. not in the Notebook, within Spyder, etc.) @user2141650's answer is more general and works in all IPython circumstances.

Comment: @LondonRob, `Ctrl-r` only seems to return the latest command which matches the pattern. Is there a shortcut like `n` in `vim` which can rotate through all the ipython commands from history?

Comment: Found it out.. seems like.. I just need to press `Ctrl-R` to cycle through the history like in bash..

Comment: Well, this is hands down the easiest way.

Answer (score 12):

I usually find myself wanting to search the entire ipython history across all previous and current sessions.  For this I use:

```
from IPython.core.history import HistoryAccessor
hista = HistoryAccessor()
z1 = hista.search('*numpy*corr*')
z1.fetchall()
```

**OR** (don't run both or you will corrupt/erase your history)

```
ip = get_ipython()
sqlite_cursor = ip.history_manager.search('*numpy*corr*')
sqlite_cursor.fetchall()
```

The search string is not a regular expression. The iPython history_manager  uses sqlite's `glob *` search syntax instead.

Comment: It uses the glob style matching described here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html#module-fnmatch

Comment: Be very careful. If you try both of the examples above in the same session you will delete your history! You need to properly close your cursor to the sqlite database to allow history to continue to work.

Comment: @hobs Thanks, but can you explain why combining the commands might corrupt your history? Or is there a way to copy the history elsewhere and open in there before playing with it like this?

Answer (score 1):

There is the way you can do it:

```
''.join(_ip.IP.shell.input_hist).split('\n')
```

or

```
''.join(_ip.IP.shell.input_hist_raw).split('\n')
```

to prevent magick expansion.

Answer (score 0):

```
from IPython.core.history import HistoryAccessor


def search_hist(pattern,
                print_matches=True,
                return_matches=True,
                wildcard=True):

    if wildcard:
        pattern = '*' + pattern + '*'
    matches = HistoryAccessor().search(pattern).fetchall()

    if not print_matches:
        return matches

    for i in matches:
        print('#' * 60)
        print(i[-1])

    if return_matches:
        return matches
```

Answer (score 0):

```
%history [-n] [-o] [-p] [-t] [-f FILENAME] [-g [PATTERN [PATTERN ...]]]
         [-l [LIMIT]] [-u]
         [range [range ...]]
```

....

```
-g <[PATTERN [PATTERN …]]>
treat the arg as a glob pattern to search for in (full) history. This includes the saved history (almost all commands ever written). The pattern may contain ‘?’ to match one unknown character and ‘*’ to match any number of unknown characters. Use ‘%hist -g’ to show full saved history (may be very long).
```

Example (in my history):

```
In [23]: hist -g cliente*aza
655/58: cliente.test.alguna.update({"orden" : 1, "nuevo" : "azafran"})
655/59: cliente.test.alguna.update({"orden" : 1} , {$set : "nuevo" : "azafran"})
655/60: cliente.test.alguna.update({"orden" : 1} , {$set : {"nuevo" : "azafran"}})
```

Example (in my history):

```
In [24]: hist -g ?lie*aza
655/58: cliente.test.alguna.update({"orden" : 1, "nuevo" : "azafran"})
655/59: cliente.test.alguna.update({"orden" : 1} , {$set : "nuevo" : "azafran"})
655/60: cliente.test.alguna.update({"orden" : 1} , {$set : {"nuevo" : "azafran"}})
```